# bson_ext 1.7.0 fails to build on Linux when using bundle:install Capistrano task

Tags: ruby, capistrano, bundler, bson-ext

Here is the error message:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/app_dir/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bson_ext-1.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/app_dir/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bson_ext-1.7.0/ext/cbson/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing bson_ext (1.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bson_ext -v '1.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried running `gem install bson_ext -v '1.7.0'` and this succeeded with no errors. I've tried installing `ruby-dev` and `ruby1.8-dev` apt packages and this did not help.

`bundle install` is able to successfully build `bson_ext` on my Mac OS X development system but is failing in the Linux production environment even when I run it directly outside of the context of the `capistrano` `bundle:install` task.

I have also tried running `gem update --system` and `gem update bundler` and this didn't help.

I suspect the issue lies in how `bundle install` is called on the target system. Still, I tried updating Capistrano to version 2.13.5 and this did not help.

Comment: What was in the log file? /var/www/app_dir/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bson_ext-1.7.0/ext/cbson/gem_make.out

Comment: Just the line `/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears that `bundler` 1.2.1 is is unable to build the following gems on my system:

- `bson_ext` 1.7.0
- `curb` 0.8.3
- `nokogiri` 1.5.5
- `json` 1.7.5
- `therubyracer` 0.8.2.

I was able to build these using `gem install <GEMNAME> -v '<VERSION>' --install-dir /var/www/<APP_DIR>/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/`. After this, running `bundle exec capistrano deploy` succeeded.

`bundle` does not appear to be able to build gems with native extensions on my system. Not sure why, but maybe this procedure will help those with a similar issue.